# How Do I Insert A Div After Certain Tags (Number) And Create Parent of Rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say my code is:

```
<div id="divname">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

</div>
```

Now, how do I do this with javascript?

```
<div id="divname">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <div class="onclick"></div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In a nutshell, I want to insert a tag after specific number of span tags and then create a parent of rest of span tags. Then when div with onclick class is clicked, the hidden div is removed and then again less span tags are covered in that parent div.

If any doubt, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start off by using the [:gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to wrap the spans:

```
var $newDiv = $("#divname > span:gt(3)").wrapAll($("<div>").addClass("hidden"));
```

Then do an insert before on the resulting div:

```
$("<div>", { class: "onclick" }).insertBefore($newDiv.parent());
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6B3Nt/) and one [with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/EJJbn/) (thanks kpull1)

Comment: @MichelAyres Works for me...you need to inspect the DOM obviously because there is no visible content